# Find n overlapping dates within n number of days

Tags: r, dplyr, data.table

I'm looking to find >=4 unique events that all occur within a group within a 90 day period and then flag the ID.

Just a test example:

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(1)

test <- data.frame(
  PATID = sample(1:1e4, 1e5, replace = TRUE),
  PROV = sample(1:50, 1e5, replace = TRUE),
  GROUP = sample(0:1, 1e5, replace = TRUE),
  DATE = as.Date(sample(
    as.Date("2020-01-01"):as.Date("2020-12-31"),
    1e5,
    replace = TRUE
  ), origin = "1970-01-01")
)
```

If we look at `PATID==5` we can see there are 4 unique `PROV`s with overlapping dates within 90 days and within our group of interest and so should be flagged.

```
> test %>% filter(PATID==5) %>% arrange(GROUP,DATE)
   PATID PROV GROUP       DATE
1      5    2     0 2020-05-07
2      5    3     0 2020-05-20
3      5    3     0 2020-11-15
4      5   49     0 2020-12-14
5      5   45     1 2020-02-16
6      5   50     1 2020-03-19
7      5   38     1 2020-03-25
8      5   27     1 2020-03-29
9      5   42     1 2020-08-30
10     5   46     1 2020-11-03
11     5   25     1 2020-11-13
12     5   29     1 2020-12-26
> as.Date("2020-03-29")-as.Date("2020-02-16")<=90
[1] TRUE
```

Ultimately, I'm looking for the proportion of `GROUP==1` vs `GROUP==0` with >=4 unique `PROVs` within 90 days. Ideally I'd prefer using data.table simply due to the scale of data.

Trying out some code:

```
test %>%
  filter(PATID %in% 1:5) %>%
  group_by(PATID,GROUP) %>%
  arrange(GROUP, DATE) %>%
  mutate(lag = DATE - lag(DATE),
         day_count = case_when(lag <= 90 ~ TRUE,
                               is.na(lag) ~ TRUE,
                               TRUE ~ FALSE)) %>%
  mutate(crit = cumsum_reset(day_count)) %>% 
  ungroup() %>%
  group_by(PATID) %>%
  mutate(flag = case_when(max(crit) >= 4 ~ 1,
                          TRUE ~ 0)) %>% 
  arrange(PATID)
```

Getting closer, just need to sort out the 90 window versus just crudely testing if each date is within 90 days.

Comment: Yes, per PATID.

Comment: Well, the flag (if that's the best system) would be at the PATID level. The proportion though would be a tally of PATIDs that do and don't meet the criteria.

Comment: what about cases where the 90d windows overlap? can you still reuse the PROV from the first window?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the following is what you are after. Please check if the logic is what you meant. I left more explicit than necessary so that the idea can be more easily understood. The main idea is that if after sorting there is a observation from same PATDI & GROUP that is within 90 days from the 3rd lag `diff_3 := DATE - shift(DATE, 3)`, than it should be flagged. This is done by checking `diff_check = diff_3<=90`. If any observation for any PATID/GROUP is flagged, the corresponding ID will be flagged by the `keep = max(diff_check, na.rm = TRUE, pmin = 0)` after grouping by only PATID.

- Using the third lag to account for 4 or more and not strictly more than 4 observations.
- Does it, all in all, make any sense?

```r
library(data.table)
set.seed(1)
test <- data.frame(
  PATID = sample(1:1e4, 1e5, replace = TRUE),
  PROV = sample(1:50, 1e5, replace = TRUE),
  GROUP = sample(0:1, 1e5, replace = TRUE),
  DATE = as.Date(sample(
    as.Date("2020-01-01"):as.Date("2020-12-31"),
    1e5,
    replace = TRUE
  ), origin = "1970-01-01")
)
test %>% filter(PATID==5) %>% arrange(GROUP,DATE)
#> Error in test %>% filter(PATID == 5) %>% arrange(GROUP, DATE): could not find function "%>%"

dt <- as.data.table(test)
dt <- dt[order(PATID, GROUP, DATE)]
dt[, diff_3 := DATE - shift(DATE, 3), by = c("PATID", "GROUP")]

# check amount of unique values of PROV in previous 4 observations
dt[, unique_last_4 := frollapply(x = PROV, n = 4, FUN = uniqueN), by = c("PATID", "GROUP")]

# check if within 90 days and unique PROVs 
dt[, diff_check := diff_3<=90 & unique_last_4==4, by = c("PATID", "GROUP")]

# final check to flag all observations of ID that satisfied at least once the above checks
dt[, to_keep := max(diff_check, na.rm = TRUE, pmin = 0), by = "PATID"]
# NOTE: unsure if you mean to group only by PATID here or by PATID & GROUP.

head(dt[to_keep==1], 20)
#>     PATID PROV GROUP       DATE   diff_3 unique_last_4 diff_check to_keep
#>  1:     5    2     0 2020-05-07  NA days            NA         NA       1
#>  2:     5    3     0 2020-05-20  NA days            NA         NA       1
#>  3:     5    3     0 2020-11-15  NA days            NA         NA       1
#>  4:     5   49     0 2020-12-14 221 days             3      FALSE       1
#>  5:     5   45     1 2020-02-16  NA days            NA         NA       1
#>  6:     5   50     1 2020-03-19  NA days            NA         NA       1
#>  7:     5   38     1 2020-03-25  NA days            NA         NA       1
#>  8:     5   27     1 2020-03-29  42 days             4       TRUE       1
#>  9:     5   42     1 2020-08-30 164 days             4      FALSE       1
#> 10:     5   46     1 2020-11-03 223 days             4      FALSE       1
#> 11:     5   25     1 2020-11-13 229 days             4      FALSE       1
#> 12:     5   29     1 2020-12-26 118 days             4      FALSE       1
#> 13:     7    1     0 2020-04-10  NA days            NA         NA       1
#> 14:     7   44     0 2020-04-29  NA days            NA         NA       1
#> 15:     7   27     0 2020-05-05  NA days            NA         NA       1
#> 16:     7   41     0 2020-06-11  62 days             4       TRUE       1
#> 17:     7   35     0 2020-06-30  62 days             4       TRUE       1
#> 18:     7   11     0 2020-12-18 227 days             4      FALSE       1
#> 19:     7   24     1 2020-12-24  NA days            NA         NA       1
#> 20:     7   13     1 2020-12-29  NA days            NA         NA       1
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

#### dplyr version

```
test_keep <- test %>% arrange(PATID, GROUP, DATE) %>%
  head(1000) %>% # otherwise it takes too long in my pc, which shows data.table's efficiency! 
  group_by(PATID, GROUP) %>%
  mutate(diff_3 = DATE - lag(DATE, 3),
         diff_check = diff_3<=90, 
         unique_last_4 = frollapply(x = PROV, n = 4, FUN = uniqueN)
  ) %>% group_by(PATID) %>%
  mutate(keep = max(diff_check, na.rm = TRUE, pmin = 0)) %>%
  arrange(PATID, GROUP)

test_keep %>% filter(keep==1) %>% head(20)
```

Comment: The example data here doesn't really show it but IRL the PROV (providers) are highly correlated to PATID (patients) so unique PROV is absolutely needed.

Comment: now its checking for PROV uniqueness. I hope it now solves your question, but please check for corner cases :)

Comment: Thanks, I think this will work for me. A good check I think is to just drop the PROV sample to something like 1:5. I didn't find any edge cases that slipped out.

Answer (score 1):

Based on  *I'm looking for the annual "group" proportion of patients that visit >=4 providers within 90 days*, you can try this:

```
library(data.table) #data.table 1.13.2
setDT(test)[, c("d90ago", "d90aft") := .(DATE - 90L, DATE + 90L)]
setkey(test, PATID, DATE)
test[, grp := 
    .SD[.SD, on=.(PATID, DATE>=d90ago, DATE<=d90aft), by=.EACHI, +(length(unique(x.PROV))>=4L)]$V1
]
```

The above allows PROV within overlapping windows of 90 days to be re-used.

Comment: Looking more into the data, I can see that this isn't a binary labeling if the criteria is met for each PATID, i.e. PATIDs belong to both `grp`. I apologize for maybe my poor description. I'm looking for patients who visit >=4 providers, the group is a prescription. So I'm looking for patients visiting >=4 different providers within a 90 day period.

Answer (score 0):

There's some ambiguities in the question, so this may not be quite right. I tried doing this using `dplyr` and local data frames, but the self-join causes an overflow (100,000 times 100,000).
It seems to work using `data.table` and using PostgreSQL, which has an `OVERLAPS` function.
(Note that I used lower-case variable names to make working with SQL easier.)

In the answer below, I start with a patient visit (`(patid, prov, group, date)` combination) and look forward 90 days to capture all visits by that patient (`patid`) to *other* providers (`prov != prov_other`). I then count the number of distinct providers in that lookahead period (this will be `NA` when there are no visits, as when looking at a patient's last visit in the sample). I then count the number of visits where the number of *additional* distinct providers in the subsequent 90 days is 3 or more.

Finally, I group by `(group, year)` and count the proportion of visits that are followed by visits to at least three other providers during the subsequent 90 days. Given the way the data are generated, it is no surprise that the two groups look similar on this metric.

Note that each patient visit forms a unit of observation here. In practice, it may make sense to aggregate by (say) `(patid, year)` before calculating statistics or do some other kind of aggregation.

```r
library(data.table)
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

set.seed(1)

test <- tibble(
    patid = sample(1:1e4, 1e5, replace = TRUE),
    prov = sample(1:50, 1e5, replace = TRUE),
    group = sample(0:1, 1e5, replace = TRUE),
    date = as.Date(sample(
        as.Date("2020-01-01"):as.Date("2020-12-31"),
        1e5,
        replace = TRUE
    ), origin = "1970-01-01")) %>%
    as.data.table()
test 
#>         patid prov group       date
#>      1:  1017    6     1 2020-08-03
#>      2:  8004   34     0 2020-12-15
#>      3:  4775   32     0 2020-06-21
#>      4:  9725   47     1 2020-09-25
#>      5:  8462   15     0 2020-03-05
#>     ---                            
#>  99996:   949   47     0 2020-07-05
#>  99997:  2723   37     0 2020-08-18
#>  99998:   201   27     1 2020-01-06
#>  99999:   163    9     0 2020-03-06
#> 100000:  3204   48     1 2020-11-17

df_overlap <- 
    test %>% 
    inner_join(test, by = "patid", suffix = c("", "_other")) %>%
    filter(prov != prov_other) %>%
    filter(date_other >= date & date_other <= date + 90L)

mt_4_provs_df <-
    df_overlap %>% 
    group_by(patid, prov, group, date) %>%
    summarize(n_providers = n_distinct(prov_other), .groups = "drop")

results <- 
    test %>%
    left_join(mt_4_provs_df, by = c("patid", "prov", "group", "date")) %>%
    mutate(mt_4_provs = n_providers >= 3,
           year = year(date)) %>%
    group_by(group, year) %>%
    summarize(prop_mt_4_provs = mean(mt_4_provs, na.rm = TRUE),
              .groups = "drop")
    
results
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>   group  year prop_mt_4_provs
#>   <int> <int>           <dbl>
#> 1     0  2020           0.426
#> 2     1  2020           0.423
```

<sup>Created on 2021-06-22 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>

Comment: I'm looking for the proportion within the groups overall not the proportion of the PROVs by group in each PATID.

Comment: I see. I may have made incorrect assumptions here because I'm wasn't totally clear on the meaning of the variables. I guess a question is whether `df_overlap` in the `data.table` version is doing what you want it to do. If so, it's probably not too difficult to tweak the later steps to get to what you want. (The main thing here seems to be that using `data.table` instead of "regular" data frames makes a big difference for a join-based solution.)

Comment: In more plain English: I'm looking for the annual "group" proportion of patients that visit >=4 providers within 90 days. So really I want this all to boil down to a single percentage number for every year while being able to walk back through each step if need be.

Comment: There seem to be many ways to count. Suppose that there is a patient who visits a new provider ever 20 days. Labelling providers `A`, `B`, …, if this patient goes alphabetically, there will be many 90-day periods with at least 4 providers: `(A, B, C, D)`, `(B, C, D, E)`, …. Some of these will overlap. In the revised answer above, I effectively count each of these periods (one starting with `A`, one starting with `B`, etc.).

A small wrinkle is that I suspect in your real data a patient is in one group or the other. But in the simulated data, patients "move" between groups.